# how to play with ordering in class based view

Tags: python, django

I'm using class based view and for instance

```
class PostListByMostViewedView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'community/mostviewed_home.html'  # <app>/<model>_<viewtype>.html
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-views']
    paginate_by = 5
```

Models.py

```
   class Post(models.Model):
        views = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

then posts are listed by view. but 
I have different model

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I want to order by the number of post.
I thought this would work

```
ordering = ['-post.comment_set.count']
```

but this fails 
no such column: post.comment_set.count

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`.annotate(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) the `Post` objects with the number of items in the `comment_set`, and then [**`.order_by(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.order_by) that annotation:

```
from django.db.models import Count

class PostListByMostViewedView(ListView):
    model = Post
    queryset = Post.objects.annotate(
        ncomments=Count('comment')
    ).order_by('-ncomments')
    template_name = 'community/mostviewed_home.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5
```

The nice thing is that every `Post` object from the queryset now has an extra attribute `ncomments` that contains the number of comments.

Comment: thank you again mr Onsem hahaha *in case anyone using this it worked with Count('comment')